# Chain promises and decorate an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to understand promises, I need to chain them and decorate an object width data from different endpoints.

For example:

I have this in my node-express app

```
//controller.js
export const getItem = (req, res) => {
    ItemService.getItem(req.params.id).then(function(item) {
        return res.json({ 'success': true, 'message': 'Item found successfully', 'item': item});
    }).catch(function(result) {
        return res.json({ 'success': false, 'errorMessage': 'Ups!' });
    });
};

//itemService.js
export const getItem = function(id){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fetch(apiUrls.getItem(id))
            .then(response => {
                if(response.ok){
                    response.json().then(data => {
                        resolve(data);
                    })
                } else {
                    reject(response.err);
                }
            });
    });
};
```

So what I want to accomplish is to decorate the data before the resolve statement. Indeed, I want to make other fetch to a different API and use the data from that response to decorate the data I'm talking about in the first place. I'll write some pseudocode:

```
fetch (api1)
   responseApi1 //{id: 123, name: 'Mike'}
   fetch (api2)
      responseApi2
      responseApi1.description = responseApi2.description
      responseApi1.address = responseApi2.address

  return responseApi1 //responseApi1 decorated width responseApi2

//Controller
return res.json({ 'success': true, 'message': 'Item found successfully', 'item': responseApi1});
```

I don't understand the promises at all, can't make this chain of promises and decorate just one object throught this promises and return it.

Comment: Both scripts are exporting a function called `getItem`, and in addition, there's an object `apiUrls` which has a property function of `getItem`? You might consider naming functions more uniquely, else it'll be very easy to confuse yourself

Comment: `fetch` is already a promise, don't do `return new Promise`,, just do `return fetch(`   & then just do -> `if (response) return response.json(); else throw response.errr;`

Comment: If api2 is not dependent on api1, I would suggest using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your "pseudo code" example (assuming both api's return JSON)

```
return fetch (api1)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(responseApi1 => fetch(api2)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(({descritpion, address}) => ({...responseApi1, description, address}))
    )
    .then(result => {
        //result is responseApi1 decorated width responseApi2
    });
```

or, if api2 does not rely on the result of api1 (which is not clear from your pseudo code)

```
return Promise.all(fetch(api1).then(res => res.json()), fetch(api2).then(res => res.json()))
    .then((responseApi1, {descritpion, address}) => ({...responseApi1, description, address}));
```

Though, I'm unsure what the `controller` section in the pseudo code is meant to be - makes no sense like you have it at all

Comment: Like you said, api2 does not rely on the result of api1. I just need to call a bunch of API and make an object width info from those responses.

Comment: So use the promise all method